# Datatype equivalent to nvarchar(max) in powerdesigner

Tags: types, sybase, powerdesigner

I created PDM from LDM in Powerdesigner.I need to generate the DB scripts for SQL Server 2014 Database.
In create table script , I have one column : status nvarchar(max) null,
I need a equivalent column in Powerdesigner to nvarchar(max) datatype.
I tried all the options from the datatype selection dropdown like Variable Multibyte, Variable Characters etc. 
But in SQL script I still see as nvarchar(4000)  or varchar(4000).
Please provide your suggestions.

Thanks ,
Vasu

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to specify in your LDM some attribute data type so that the resulting physical data type is nvarchar(max)?

I'd suggest attaching a Domain to such attributes in the Logical Model.

After the first generation from LDM to PDM, you change to domain physical data type to nvarchar(max).

On the next generations from LDM to PDM, you make sure the `Preserve Modifications` checkbox is checked. And the physical data type change to nvarchar(max) will override the default generated data type of nvarchar(4000).

I guess it would work by making the change directly on each column, it is just easier to maintain by attaching a domain...